# phpmailer 500: internal server error on hosting, but on localhost its works well

Tags: php, localhost, hosting, phpmailer

I try to send email through phpmailer. On the localhost server (127. 0. 0. 1), it works well. But, after I uploaded on hosting web (not localhost), it does not work and I get 500: internal server error. I have tried in different hosting, but still get the same mistake. What happened?

Comment: Are you using dynamic links/paths and such? Otherwise it might be looking in the wrong location.

Comment: Please diagnose the error and post some details, and check your email config. Currently, this is too vague to give an answer.

Comment: Are you using SMTP or the local mail function? For SMTP enable debugging (set it to 2). If you're using the local mail function try a simple PHP script that sends you a test email not using PHPMailer.

Comment: Any other ideas? All of your comments is not work :(

Answer (score 0):

If you send mails from a domain that is not associated with your online server, some providers may deny sending the mail. The error for that may vary, so check your outgoing mail address. 
If that fails, create a mail account and use this account with authorisation in your mailer config.